# How to access session variables in a PHP script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a "notifications" function but when I execute a jQuery function where I call my "NOTIFICACIONES.php" script using AJAX, what my php script does is to call some info from the database. I use the Id from the current user to call the data but in my ajax "success function" I just catch an empty array.

I wrote a test script so I can echo every step of my function but when i run my "test script" I noticed that my session variable it's empty

This is my login code where I set all my PHP session variables.

```php
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['empresa']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['usuario']))
        {
            if(isset($_POST['password']))
            {

                $empresa = $_POST["empresa"];
                $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];

                $host = "localhost";
                $bd = "nominet_Directorio_Web_Beta";
                $us = "nominet_Marvin2";
                $pas = "NominetBD2019!";

                error_reporting(0);

                $con = new mysqli($host, $us, $pas, $bd);

                if($con->connect_errno)
                {
                    echo "Error de conexión al servidor de base de datos...";
                    exit(); 
                }

                mysqli_set_charset('utf8');

                $query = "SELECT `Tbl_Usuarios`.`Id`, `Tbl_Usuarios`.`Fk_Empresa`, `Tbl_Usuarios`.`Tipo_Usuario` FROM `Tbl_Usuarios` INNER JOIN `Tbl_Empresas` ON `Tbl_Usuarios`.`Fk_Empresa` = `Tbl_Empresas`.`Id` WHERE `Tbl_Usuarios`.`Usuario` = '" . $usuario . "' AND `Tbl_Usuarios`.`Password` = '" . $password . "' AND `Tbl_Empresas`.`Razon_Social` = '" . $empresa . "'";
                //$query = "SELECT `Tbl_Administradores`.`Id` FROM `Tbl_Administradores` WHERE `Tbl_Administradores`.`Usuario` = '" . $usuario . "' AND `Tbl_Administradores`.`Password` = '" . $password . "'";

                $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                $res= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

                if($res["Id"] > 0)
                {

                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION["Id"] = $res["Id"];
                    $_SESSION["Empresa"] = $res["Fk_Empresa"];
                    $_SESSION["Usuario"] = $usuario;
                    $_SESSION["Tipo_Usuario"] = $res["Tipo_Usuario"];

                    header("Location: ../SISTEMA/");
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: ../?error=0");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: ../?resp=error1");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: ../?error=2");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ../?error=3");
    }
?>
```

```
function verificarNotificaciones(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "/PHP/NOTIFICACIONES.php",
        type: "POST",
        error: function(xhr){
          // window.location.href = "../CONTACTOS/?resp=7";
        },
        success: function(respuesta) {

            var arreglo = JSON.parse(respuesta);

        }
    });

}
```

```
<?php

    require("ABRIR_CON.php");

    session_start();

    $fk_usuario = $_SESSION['Id']; //this is the problem (I think...)

    $query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Id`, `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Folio`, `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Medio_Contacto`, `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Fecha_Cita`, `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Hora_Cita`, `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Fecha_Registro`, `Tbl_Contactos`.`Razon_Social` FROM `Tbl_Seguimientos` INNER JOIN `Tbl_Contactos` ON `Tbl_Contactos`.`Id` = `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Fk_Contacto` WHERE `Tbl_Seguimientos`.`Fk_Usuario` = ' . $fk_usuario);

    $json = array();

    $fecha_actual = getdate();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        list($dia, $mes, $year) = explode("/", $arreglo['Fecha_Cita']);
        list($hora, $minutos) = explode(":", $arreglo['Hora_Cita']);

        if((int)$year == $fecha_actual['year']){
            if((int)$mes >= $fecha_actual['mon']){
                if((int)$dia >= $fecha_actual['mday']){
                    if((int)$hora >= $fecha_actual['hours']){
                        if((int)$minutos > $fecha_actual['minutes']){

                            $json[]=array('id' => $row['Id'], 'folio'=> $row['Folio'], 'medio_contacto'=> $row['Medio_Contacto'], 'fecha_cita'=> $row['Fecha_Cita'], 'hora_cita'=> $row['Hora_Cita'], 'fecha_registro'=> $row['Fecha_Registro'], 'razon_social'=> $row['Razon_Social']);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        elseif((int)$year > $fecha_actual['year']){

            $json[]=array('id' => $row['Id'], 'folio'=> $row['Folio'], 'medio_contacto'=> $row['Medio_Contacto'], 'fecha_cita'=> $row['Fecha_Cita'], 'hora_cita'=> $row['Hora_Cita'], 'fecha_registro'=> $row['Fecha_Registro'], 'razon_social'=> $row['Razon_Social']);

        }

    }

    $resources_JSON_array = json_encode($json);
    echo ($resources_JSON_array);

    require("CERRAR_CON.php");

?>
```

My php script is supposed to give me a Json Array with the info that has passed through the multiple if's

Comment: @Dharman thanks, I'll have everything you said on consideration to improve my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would comment, but have to reply here due to 50 cred limitation. Make sure your browsers cookies are on. Console.log any ajax data to see if you are sending data to be received by php. Move session_start at beginning of code ie line 1. Hope one of these helps.

Comment: Actually I don't send any data on the AJAX request, all the data I need is the session "Id" variable that I set when my user logins